# Where can I have a client edit JSON files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

If my client is not comfortable with manually editing the JSON files that drive their data, what is the best way to have them edit the JSON file? A cross-platform app would work, or a website that doesn't look like it was thrown together overnight.

Anything that looks professional and modern, for that matter, is what they are looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you just make them some sort of data entry front end? I wouldn't be comfortable with non-programmer customers editing raw JSON at all ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsoneditor.net/

it has a simple but effective graphical interface to add/update/delete nodes

Answer (score 2):

If your client doesn't feel comfortable editing JSON, then I'd question whether giving them a GUI to edit JSON will help. Maybe they need a proper GUI e.g. "Edit Preferences" or "New Foobar Wizard". Just a thought.